# DB.SESSION.COMMIT() Not adding data to the database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add new data to my database, everything works fine so far. However when Im attempting to update my database via ipython, its not updating once I type in DB.SESSION.COMMIT() nothing happens. Please help if you can

app.py
[here is a copy of the app.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlYtv.png)

Models.py
[here is a copy of my Models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go8bH.png)

This is a screenshot of what happens when I try to commit data to my db
[ipython screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Y8v.png)

Nothing happens it just goes to the next line. Does anyone know why its not adding the data?

Comment: What were you expecting it to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was returned was the default representation of that entry in your database. If you want to change it, you have to override the `__repr__` method of your `User` model.

Here is an example, (add it to your `User` class):

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<User {} {}>".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

This should return `<User whiskey2 dog2>` for your example.